# How can I stop event when I click on sprites (three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have 2 sprites, when I try to put second sprite near the first sprite, the event of the fist sprite happen.
I try to stop the event with:

```
event.preventDefault()
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
event.stopPropagation()
```

but didn't stop the event

this return true:

```
var x = event.cancelable;
```

How can I stop this event?

Thanks,
Anna

Comment: Please write that script here.

Comment: In order for us to better understand your problem, can you please explain the way the events take from the browser into three.js (or, even better add a code-snippet)? Generally, when rendering in webgl, three.js only uses a single canvas-element so the dom-event methods above will not do anything useful. There has to be some place in your code (anything to do with raycasting maybe?) that handles the events and that is where your problem is and should be fixed.

Comment: Martin is correct, but I'd like to re-state his comment with a different twist. You can't attach DOM-level events (click, mouseup, hover) to THREE.js objects--they'll never receive the events. Instead, you use DOM-level events (usually attached to the canvas) to initiate querying THREE.js (specific object properties, use a raycaster to find an object under the cursor, etc.). In your case, you would use a raycaster to detect which sprite was under your mouse during the canvas's click event, and respond accordingly.